# Is it possible to have a shorthand local variable in ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

In Angular 2 ngFor, is it possible to declare a local (short-hand) variable? I mean something like this, but I am not sure about the syntax:

```
<li *ngFor="let userHasAgenda of agendas | async;
    let agenda=userHasAgenda.agenda">
```

The hypothetical part in question: `let agenda=userHasAgenda.agenda`.
Trying something like that, angular gives me:
`Parser Error: Unexpected token ., expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 43 in [let uha of agendas | async; let agenda=uha.agenda;]`

Edit 1:
For comparison, I know this is possible, for example, with index/first/last:

```
<li *ngFor="let task of tasks | async;
    let i = index;
    let isFirst = first;
    let isLast = last;"
```

But is it allowed to have custom "aliased variables" ??

Comment: Currently, angular doesn't support assigning arbitrary values. What's the purpose of doing such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, according to this GitHub issue ([*Support assigning expression result to local variable within templates*](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2451)), it isn't supported, but there is hope:

> **14 Dec 2016**
>
> Probably something we can consider at a later point according to usage needs.

For now, we have to stick to the [five NgFor local variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html): `index`, `first`, `last`, `even` and `odd`